# How to rewrite a cURL request to VBA WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1

Tags: vba, curl, winhttprequest

I have a cURL request which I'm able to run via Windows PowerShell:

```
curl -k -X GET "https://api.xxx.com/open/api/exchange-rates/v1/exchange-rates?validityDateTime=2023-03-30T06%3A00%3A00.000Z" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "x-correlation-id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -H  "x-api-key: Bearer aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

*(URL and API keys replaced with "x" or "a")*

How would I request this via MS Access VBA, with **WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1**?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
Dim HTTPReq As Object
Dim URL As String

Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "https://api.xxx.com/open/api/exchange-rates/v1/exchange-rates/USD?validityDateTime=2019-03-27T06%3A00%3A00.000Z"

HTTPReq.Open "GET", URL, False
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "x-correlation-id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", "Bearer aaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa"
HTTPReq.send

Debug.Print HTTPReq.responseText

Set HTTPReq = Nothing
```

If anyone else finds this helpful :)